# Getting error: The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am getting the error `The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.` for the following query.
After checking some questions here I was able to know the date format of my sql server by running `SELECT GETDATE()` and what I got was `2015-06-11 15:58:01.473` which seems like the format i am using to insert the data. What am I doing wrong?

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT cms_clients ON
INSERT INTO cms_clients (id, user_id, firstname, lastname, middlename, pseudoname, dob, photo, careplan1, careplan2, gender, program, csscentre, managing_csc, unique_ref_no, cur_weight, tar_weight, benf_ent_number, med_number, drugs_alert, prescriber_particulars, special_considerations, vaccinations, dom, doa, status, address, medicare_expiry_date, telephone, date_of_annual_health_care_plan, first_language, interp_req, religion, religious_considerations, diagnosis_and_associated_health_conditions, communcation, challenging_behaviours, medicare_number, pension_number, private_health_insurance, person_responsible, person_res_name, person_res_address, person_res_telephone_h, person_res_telephone_w, person_res_telephone_m, person_res_email, decision_making_function, relative, guardian_name, guardian_address, guardian_telephone_h, guardian_telephone_w, guardian_telephone_m, guardian_email, health_number, entry_date, exit_date, mobile_no, spoken_lang, known_address, written_directives, significant_other, additional_info, school_program, school_address, school_contact, school_phone, school_transport, families_social, families_email, families_snr, families_supervisor, families_fsa, families_address, families_phone, families_fax, curfew_fsa, curfew_mpr, youth_allowance, pocket_money, bail_cond, details, court_date, transport_via, location, pract_name, pract_relationship, pract_phone, pract_fax, pract_address, pract_email, approved_name, approved_relationship, approved_phone, med_expiry_date) VALUES
(1, '', 'test', 'test', '', '', '2015-06-05', '', '', '9', 'M', '', '', '', '', 0, 0, '', '', '', '', '', '', '2015-06-04 06:00:50', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 'A', '', '1970-01-01', '', '1970-01-01', '', 0, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 0, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '0000-00-00', '0000-00-00', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '0000-00-00'),
(180, '', 'test 2', 'test', '', '', '2015-06-05', '', '', '10', 'M', '', '', '', '', 0, 0, '', '', '', '', '', '', '2015-06-04 06:00:50', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 'A', '', '1970-01-01', '', '1970-01-01', '', 0, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 0, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '0000-00-00', '0000-00-00', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '0000-00-00'),
(181, '', 'test 3', 'test', '', '', '2015-06-05', '', '', '8', 'M', '', '', '', '', 0, 0, '', '', '', '', '', '', '2015-06-04 06:00:50', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 'A', '', '1970-01-01', '', '1970-01-01', '', 0, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 0, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '0000-00-00', '0000-00-00', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '0000-00-00'),
(182, '', 'Ted', 'Mosbey', '', '', '2015-06-10', '', '', '10', 'M', '', '', '', '', 0, 0, '', '', '', '', '', '', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '2015-06-09 05:54:50', 'A', '', '1970-01-01', '', '1970-01-01', '', 0, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 0, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '0000-00-00', '0000-00-00', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '0000-00-00');
```

Comment: Please clean up your example - it contains a zillion of non-time-related columns which obviously cannot be the source of your problem.  All those columns just add noise, making it harder to find the real problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values '0000-00-00' are causing this error. You could for example use NULL instead.